# How does the Maven Transitive dependencies flow work?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

I am new to Maven so still trying to understand how it works. I have a library **B** which is dependent on **A**. So **A** is added in dependency of **B**.
I have project **C** which is dependent on  **B** and also on **A**. 
So if I add B library as in C's POM then the transitive dependency should work and C should see A. **C -> B -> A**

I see my colleague has written something like following in C's POM :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>B</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>C</groupId>
                <artifactId>C</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>C</groupId>
        <artifactId>C</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I look into B's pom , I find that there is no packaging information. So it is neither a jar nor a war. It is being just used a library.

My question is , does the library's(B) dependent modules are passed as transitive dependencies to the Project(C) which is using library(B) in its dependency.

Comment: It makes no sense to exclude an Artifact just to add it again. Your colleague is doing something wrong, especially if there are no comments to explain why he does this.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please check again.

Comment: I answered the question, but the code doesn't match the question. You should edit the source to make everything coherent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes : Maven resolves the whole dependency tree then configures your project accordingly. You can see this resolution with the goal [`dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)

When you include **B** in your project **C**, Maven reads **B**'s `pom.xml` which includes **A** transitively. Maven then flattens this tree, solves the conflicts if any, and configures two dependencies for your project.

Your project **C** can now access **A** and **B** as if they were integrated.

---

Note that the Maven plugin in Eclipse (if you use it) is pretty smart and can decide to use a JAR or the project files directly if it's available in your workspace. This can lead to some confusion, but in-fine; it works.